# Field 'login' doesn't have a default value in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I created a domain class `Resource` with `login` and `password` fields. I generated controllers and views but after I want to delete these field login and password and generating views and controllers but I have an error. My domain class:

```
package tachemanagement

class Resource {

    String nom
    String prenom

    static hasMany = [taches: Tache]

    static belongsTo = [projet: Project]

    static constraints = {
        nom(blank:false)
        prenom(blank:false)         
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
URI
/tachemanagement/resource/save
Class
java.sql.SQLException
Message
Field 'login' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: Did you delete your DB tables before re-running? Do you have any bootstrap.groovy code creating DB objects? Did you try a `grails clean-all`? What is your datasource `dbCreate` value?

Comment: yes yesterday i deleted my DB tables and its doing well thanks